# Instructions not executed into the right order with nodejs

Tags: node.js, cat

I am new to nodejs and trying to cat multiple css files on-the-fly while coding. The package chokidar allow me to call a function when a file is modified, however I have a problem with the execution.

```
var goconcat =
  fs.readdir(paths, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {console.log(err);}
      fs.unlink(paths + 'concat.css', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var list = files.map(function (files) {
            return path.join(paths, files);
        });
        concat(list, paths + 'concat.css',  function(err) {
          if (err) throw err
        });
      });
});
```

I want to first delete the previous file, then read the directory and then write a new "concat.css". However I have an error;

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/css/concat.css'
at error (native)
```

It appears that the function concat() is executed before the directory update and not after, and therefore it is trying to cat a file that just have been deleted. Why ?

I know that nodejs is executing functions in a synchronous way but I can't find a way to solve this problem. I tried async but I can't declare a variable between two functions and I couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Do not use settimeout functions in production though, u never know what values you will hard code and where it will start breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it cannot exist in a callback, using the `setTimeout(fn, 0)` trick may help make sure it's executed after the variable assignment.

```
var goconcat =
  fs.readdir(paths, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {console.log(err);}
      fs.unlink(paths + 'concat.css', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var list = files.map(function (files) {
            return path.join(paths, files);
        }); 
        setTimeout(function() {
          concat(list, paths + 'concat.css',  function(err) {
            if (err) throw err
        })}, 0);
      });
});
```

Comment: Because it was the most simple and because I do not worry about blocking the code for development I used your solution with 10ms and it worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that your `concat` function is being invoked before the file is deleted by invoking `unlink`. You can prevent this by having nested callbacks; however, you can probably have better `control flow` if you use a module like `async`, and prevent yourself from dealing with [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Below is an example on how you can use the `async` module.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

var myDir = __dirname + '/data';

async.waterfall([function(callback) {
    fs.readdir(myDir, 'utf-8', function(error, files) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }

        return callback(null, files);
    });
}, function(files, callback) {
    fs.open(myDir + '/myFile', 'wx', function(error, f) {
        if (error && error.code === 'EEXIST') {
            return callback(null, 'EEXIST');
        }

        return callback(null, 'CREATE');
    });
}, function(fileStatus, callback) {
    if (fileStatus === 'EEXIST') {
        console.log('File exists. Deleting file...');

        fs.unlink(myDir + '/myFile', function(error) {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            } else {
                return callback(null);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('File does not exist...');

        return callback(null);
    }
}, function(callback) {
    fs.writeFile(myDir + '/myFile', "Hello World", function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return callback(error);
        }

        return callback(null, 'File Created');
    }); 
}], function(error, results) {
    console.error(error);
    console.log(results);
});
```

> The [waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) function runs the tasks array of functions in series,
>   each passing their results to the next in the array. However, if any
>   of the tasks pass an error to their own callback, the next function is
>   not executed, and the main callback is immediately called with the
>   error.

Comment: I did not ended using your solution but it appears to be the most rigorous one. I tried to use async but failed, your explication helped me understand my mistakes so thank you